# How does one classify the words in "how about" and "what about"?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

I see in other posts that "how", while typically classified as an adverb, can be considered an adjective when paired with a "be" form (e.g. "how is the pizza?"). But in the case of the phrase "how about tomorrow" is "how" an adverb? And what is the appropriate classification of "about"? Finally, does this change if you add to the phrase an 's, as in "how's about tomorrow" (which may not be entirely grammatical, but common in informal speech).

Comment: 'How' in interrogatives is a [wh-]-interrogative word which some like to subsume into adverbs under the term 'interrogative adverbs'. Here, it may be that there is a deletion from "How do you feel about tomorrow?" say. // Adding the apostrophe-_s_? There comes a time when John Lawler's advice "What exactly have you gained if you manage to find a way of POS-tagging an orthographic word?" (owtte) is the only comment to make. Apart from, perhaps "And if you can't shoehorn it into an existing group ...?" (Bend the rules? Invent a new group?)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Thanks for the analysis regarding "how", but what's your call on "about"? Even in your expansion "how do you feel about tomorrow", what classification seems fit for "about"?

Comment: "About" is a preposition creating an adjectival prepositional modifier. How about tomorrow = "What is your opinion about tomorrow [as an appropriate/convenient date]?"